# Which Bleach productions are canon and needed to understand Bleach: Thousand-Year Blood War?

Tags: bleach

As far as I know, Bleach have several productions like light novels, manga, anime, animated movies and even a Live Action. Different franchises treat differently different productions, so in some franchises for example, animated movies are canon and in others are not, and even in some like Dragon Ball some movies are canon and others are not, and some series are canon and others are not. How does this work in Bleach?

Which Bleach productions are canon and needed to understand Bleach: Thousand-Year Blood War?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Spoiler alert:** Wikipedia has a few spoilers in its summary.

To my understanding, the Thousand-Year Blood War follows the original manga where it picked up after the Fullbring arc which [is in fact canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bleach_chapters_(424%E2%80%93686)).

So long as you've followed either (or both) the manga and the anime, you should be OK.

No guarantees on whether or not they reintroduce filler-arc characters or characters from other media, but the vast majority of the story *should* be coming from the manga.

Comment: Cross-checking the manga chapters from [the last episode of *Bleach* anime](https://bleach.fandom.com/wiki/Changing_History,_Unchanging_Heart) and [the first episode of *Bleach: Thousand-Year Blood War* anime](https://bleach.fandom.com/wiki/The_Blood_Warfare_(episode)) reveals that it continues directly, just as Wikipedia stated it as "direct sequel".